# Validation and return false not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, internet-explorer-9

My submit + validation function is failing only on IE9. I rewrote the `document.home_form.name.value` to `document.['home_form']['name'].value` as I don't believe the conditions are being met, but it still fails. I also have read that `event.preventDefault();` isn't a valid argument in IE9 if there isn't an `addEventHandler`, I tried switching it out to `event.returnValue = false;` and it still failed. The `home_form()` function still runs and submits the data, and is why I have not included it.

```
$('#home_form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    validate();
    if(document.home_form.name.value == "" || document.home_form.tel.value == "" || document.home_form.email.value == "" ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        home_form();
        $('.hf-inner').hide();
        $('#home-form-thanks').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});

function validate() {
    return $("input,textarea,select").removeClass('blank').filter(function() {
        return !/\S+/.test($(this).val());
    }).addClass('blank').size() == 0;
}
```